# I don't understand the following paragraph.What does it mean by "empathizing with someone"?

Tags: meaning

Source: SAT Practice Test 2 Reading Test for Assistive Technology - The College Board

> There are different views on where ethics should apply when someone makes an economic decision. Consider Adam Smith, widely regarded as the founder of modern economics. He was a moral philosopher who believed sympathy for others was the basis for ethics (we would call it empathy nowadays). But one of his key insights in The Wealth of Nations was that acting on this empathy could be counter-productive—he observed people becoming better off when they put their own empathy aside, and interacted in a self-interested way. Smith justifies selfish behavior by the outcome. Whenever planners use cost-benefit analysis to justify a new railway line, or someone retrains to boost his or her earning power, or a shopper buys one to get one free, they are using the same approach: **empathizing with someone**, and seeking an outcome that makes that person as well off as possible—although the person they are empathizing with may be themselves in the future.

Comment: It's one paragraph on the SAT @JonMarkPerry and others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Empathy definition from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/empathy):

> 1. the psychological identification with or vicarious experiencing of the feelings, thoughts, or attitudes of another.
> 2. the imaginative ascribing to an object, as a natural object or work of art, feelings or attitudes present in oneself

This passage is talking about empathy in the context of putting yourself in someone else's shoes in order to make a decision, even if that someone else is future you.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your kind comment. :) What I have still confused about is that the text doesn't make sense to me. In the front part of the paragraph it says that Adam Smith thought acting on empathy would be counter-productive, and the last sentence says that people do economic decisions by empathizing. How can a person put aside empathy and at the same time empathize someone?

Comment: Ah roger that thanks for clearing it up. I believe the passage is meant to show how empathizing with the you of the future is self-interested yet still using empathy. It is a seeming contradiction but for the subtle nuance of considering future you a person capable of being empathized with. In short, the aim is to justify self-interest or selfish behavior by saying you are still being empathetic to someone - yourself.

Comment: That was great help, thank you! This is the first time I use this website, and I think I have got a great explanation of my problem.

Comment: Great! Glad to help :) if you like the answer, you can mark it as answered with the little check mark.

Comment: Hello, J. Tate. Answering a question that is clearly off-topic encourages similar questions. I don't usually downvote answers for this reason if the answerer has less than 1000 rep, but when they also ask that the answer be accepted, I may make an exception.